# Как исправить проблему со 100vh на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивность

При определении высоты блока как 100vh, на мобильных устройствах верхнее меню браузера прибавляется к общей высоте, появляется вертикальный скролл и нижние элементы съезжают. Кто знает как фиксить?

Comment: неплохо бы код увидеть

Comment: @Tigran Vardanyan <section class="main">//main wrapper</section> .main { height: 100vh; width: 100%; pos: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; } .Его высота на мобильных учитывает верхний бар браузера..и из-за этого появляется скролл

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, никак. Только костылями, типа такого:

```
//Предварительно делаем мобайл детект
//...
if ($('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
  //добавляем inline стиль, в котором фиксируем высоту титульного блока
  $('.main').css({ height: window.innerHeight });
}
```